# Error while reading from input stream using Node Canvas API in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express, canvas

I'm currently making a program that combines 2 images together in javascript, I'm doing this by loading the images with the `loadImage()` function from the [Node Canvas API](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#loadimage) and drawing the image to the `context` of a `canvas`.

Here is the javascript code for file `canvas.js` for reference.

```js
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require("canvas");
const fs = require("fs");

const canvas = createCanvas(0, 0, "png");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

try {
    const picture = loadImage(`../image.png`);
    const frame = loadImage(`../frame.png`);
    Promise.all([picture, frame]).then((response) => {
      response.map((image, index) => {
        if (index === 0) {
          canvas.width = image.width;
          canvas.height = image.height;
          context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        } else {
          context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          // Outputs the canvas object
          fs.writeFileSync("../framed/out.png", canvas.toBuffer());
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

I was successfully able to output a file the other day, but now when I run the code, I receive the following error in the console:

```
Error: error while reading from input stream
    at setSource (/api/node_modules/canvas/lib/image.js:91:13)
    at Image.set (/api/node_modules/canvas/lib/image.js:62:9)
    at /api/node_modules/canvas/index.js:34:15
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at loadImage (/api/node_modules/canvas/index.js:23:10)
    at frameImage (/api/src/canvas.js:9:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/api/src/canvas.js:30:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
```

I'm not sure what to make of it other than suspect that the argument I'm passing into `loadImage()` is incorrect, but that may not be the case.

Comment: has your `image.png` or `frame.png` been moved to a different location / has been deleted? Or are you running your code from a different folder than you were few days ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the issue was how I was handling the order of my post request uploading an image, and then combining the images. Because I did not account for that, the `writefile()` function was interrupted, saving a corrupted image file to my local storage.